# Calling Remote Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

Basically, Google Adwords give you a code so you can track how well your campaigns are working. You put in on your order thank you page to track and order, so you can see which keywords bring in the most orders. It gives me a code like this:

```
<!-- Google Code for Purchase/Sale Conversion Page -->
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
var google_conversion_id = xxxxxxxxxx;
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "1";
var google_conversion_color = "666666";
var google_conversion_label = "purchase";
//-->
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>
<noscript>
<img height="1" width="1" border="0" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/xxxxxxxxxx/?label=purchase&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
</noscript>
```

When the user clicks one of my ads it sets a cookie with the keyword he clicked from etc, and then when he reaches this bit of a JS on the thank you page it realises he has a cookie and does the necessary tracking.

The problem is, for the thing I'm promoting right now the order thank you page is not on my server. I can place javascript on the page to track orders but only in the following format:

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript" src="xxxx"></SCRIPT>
```

With the 'xxxx' bit being the only thing I can change.

If I put the Google JS code in a file on my server, and then call the file on my server from his thank you page, will it achieve the same effect? If not is there any way to do this using what I have available?

Comment: In fact I think I can just use the bit of the script between the noscript area and place it as a pixel. I'd still like a response anyway to see if it's possible the other way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not tracking prices or anything but just conversions as defined by a page hit, then you could also go the iframe route. Have the client site open an iframe pointing to your server which then includes the googel code. Personally though, I think the pixel option is better, so long as it is not disallowed or ignored by Google (you will have to experiement to find out if this is the case)